# AngularJS authentication using localStorage

Tags: angularjs, authentication, jwt

I have created an angular application where I'm using jwt for authenticating every api call to server. At client side I'm setting loggedIn to true in localStorage once user log in. And then I'm using the AuthService on ui router stateChangeStart event which checks whether loggedIn in localStorage is true or not.

I have seen many examples where they save username in localStorage and later on check for whether username is set or not to figure out whether user is authenticated or not. But my question is, localStorage can be tempered and anyone can set username property to something or set loggedIn to true.

Whats your thoughts on this, and is there something I'm missing.

Comment: can you share your code

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is, just store the token in localStorage or better save a header JSON as follows

```
if (response.data.token) // response for successful login
  {
    let headers = {
      ContentType  : 'application/json',
      access-token : response.data.token,
      anyOtherHeader: 'xxx'
    }

    window.localStorage.setItem('headers',JSON.stringify(headers));
  }
```

and just check for this whenever app loads, and if it exist, if it does keep it in $rootScope

```
let headers = window.localStorage.getItem('headers');
if(headers){
   $rootScope.headers = JSON.parse(headers);
   $timeout(function(){$scope.$apply()}) //to update your app about token
}
```

and whenever your token is not authenticated/not verified/logged out just delete it from localStorage and $rootScope

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('headers')
$rootScope.headers = undefined;
$timeout(function(){$scope.$apply()}); //again to update your app about it
```

With appropriate error handling, it works great for me. although it can be tempered with, it can't be misused. Let me know if this helps :)